# Let $P(A) = 0.36$, $P(B) = 0.45$, and $P(A \cup B) = 0.55$.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $P(A) = 0.36$, $P(B) = 0.45$, and $P(A \cup B) = 0.55$.

a)  $P(B \cap A) = 0.26$

b)  $P(B \mid A) = 0.72$

c) Are $A$ and $B$ independent? $A$ and $B$ are not independent since $P(B \cap A) = 0.26$ and $P(A) \cdot P(B)=0.162$, so $P(B \cap A)$ does not equal $P(A) \cdot P(B)$.

Could you please check it for me?

Comment: you are correct

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Formally only c) can be checked. You should add how you arrived at the numbers you mention. Checking your method? Okay. Working as a calculator? No.

Answer (score 5):

We see that by inclusion-exclusion,
$$P(B \cap A) = P(B) + P(A) - P(A \cup B)$$
$$= .36 + .45 - .55 = .26,$$
So you ar correct about that. Since $P(A) \cdot P(B) = .36 \cdot .45 = .162 \neq .26.$, It is apparent that $P(A) \cdot P(B) \neq P(A \cap B),$ and so $A$ and $B$ are not independent.

Answer (score 0):

For a), just use the basic formula $P(A\cup B)+P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)$.

For b), just write what the conditional probability $P(B|A)$ is (by formula), use a) and you're done.